# Pyarrow 0.15.1 uploading empty files to HDFS

Tags: upload, hdfs, pyarrow

Hi I am trying to upload a csv file to my HDFS cluster using the upload method in pyarrow Hadoop File System Interface:

```
import pyarrow as pa

fs = pa.hdfs.connect(host, port, user)
with open('test.csv') as f:
   pa.hdfs.HadoopFileSystem.upload(fs, '/data/test.csv', f)
```

This for some reason always uploads an empty file with 0B to the HDFS in pyarrow version 0.15.1. But when downgrading to pyarrow version 0.10.0, the file gets uploaded correctly.

I am using HDFS version 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```py
with open('test.csv','rb') as f:
```

This is probably because the file contains some non-unicode characters and it needs to be read as a binary.